# How to map values in the db, to my objects when the type is known at runtime?

Tags: c#

My database has a table that looks like:

```
conditionID, conditionType, conditionValue
```

`ConditionType` is an enumeration with values like Integer, String, DateTime, etc.

The ConditionValue is stored as a string.

Now I want to encapsulate this row in a class such that I can perform comparison's on the ConditionValue, so this like EqualTo, GreaterThan, LessThan etc.

At the moment my design isn't correct because I have methods like (`otherValue` is the value I am comparing against):

```
GreaterThan(string value, string otherValue);
GreaterThan(int value, int otherValue);
GreaterThan(DateTime value, DateTime otherValue);
```

**Could I somehow make a ConditionValue class that encapsulates this information so I can do:**

```
GreaterThan(IConditionValue condition, IConditionValue otherValue)
```

Comment: Have a look at Generics. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You need to take a look at the links in my first post. The encapsulating of data type specific functionality is AOM or simplified variations, such as the Type Object pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This should be easily be able to be modeled using the Adaptive Object Model or Type Object patterns. It might be over kill for your situation though.

http://adaptiveobjectmodel.com/

http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/dpa/typeobject.pdf

It allows you to reconfigure your model at run-time, add/remove behavior at will, define rules, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very naive example.

```
public class ConditionValue
{
    private object value;
    private IValueType valueType;

    public ConditionValue(object value, IValueType valueType)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.valueType = valueType;
    }

    public bool GreaterThan(ConditionValue cv)
    {
        return valueType.GreaterThan(this.value, cv.value);
    }
}

public interface IValueType
{
    bool GreaterThan(object left, object right);
}

public class IntegerType : IValueType
{
    public bool GreaterThan(object left, object right)
    {
        return (int)left > (int)right;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok this makes this more clearer for me, I can also check if its a collection in the integer.GreaterThan method etc.

Comment: You can use the IValueType<TType> interface to define your data type "archetypes" that will be stored in the database. Have a factory method that takes in the conditionType enum and returns an instance of ConditionValue using the value and the IValueType handler for that enum value.

Comment: and that factory will return an int, string or a List<string>?  hmmm..not sure I get it yet sorry.

Answer (score 1):

All of the types you mentioned implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx), so you can simply assume the type will be IComparable and use the CompareTo() method.

```
bool GreaterThan(IComparable value, IComparable otherValue)
{
    return value.CompareTo(otherValue) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public enum ValueType
    {
        String = 0,
        Integer = 1,
        CustomDataType = 3
    }

    public interface IValueType : IComparer<object>
    {
        string ToString(object obj);
    }

    public class IntegerValueType : IValueType
    {
        public int Compare(object left, object right)
        {
            return ((int)left).CompareTo((int)right);
        }

        public string ToString(object obj)
        {
            return ((int)obj).ToString();
        }
    }

    public class StringValueType : IValueType
    {
        public int Compare(object left, object right)
        {
            return ((string)left).CompareTo((string)right);
        }

        public string ToString(object obj)
        {
            return ((string)obj).ToString();
        }
    }

    public class Value : IComparable<Value>
    {
        private object value;
        private IValueType valueType;

        public Value(object value, IValueType valueType)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.valueType = valueType;
        }

        public static implicit operator Value(string value)
        {
            return ValueFactory.Create(value, ValueType.String);
        }

        public int CompareTo(Value obj)
        {
            return this.valueType.Compare(this.value, obj.value);
        }

        public static bool operator <(Value left, Value right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) == -1;
        }

        public static bool operator >(Value left, Value right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) == 1;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(Value left, Value right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) == 0;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(Value left, Value right)
        {
            return left.CompareTo(right) != 0;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.valueType.ToString(this.value);
        }
    }

    public class ValueFactory
    {
        private static IDictionary<object, IValueType> _valueTypes =
            new Dictionary<object, IValueType>();

        static ValueFactory()
        {
            _valueTypes.Add(ValueType.String, new StringValueType());
            _valueTypes.Add(ValueType.Integer, new IntegerValueType());
        }

        public static Value Create(object value, object valueType)
        {
            //
            // This logic could be extended to find a ValueType that supports
            // one of the types in the objects inheritance tree. This would
            // also require creating an ObjectValueType, which would be a last
            // resort in the case of the object type not being supported.
            //
            if (!_valueTypes.ContainsKey(valueType))
                throw new ArgumentException("valueType is not supported");

            return new Value(value, _valueTypes[valueType]);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 32;
            int y = 16;

            Value cx = ValueFactory.Create(x, ValueType.Integer);
            Value cy = ValueFactory.Create(y, ValueType.Integer);

            Console.WriteLine("cx = "+cx);
            Console.WriteLine("cy = "+cy);
            Console.WriteLine("x<y = {0}", cx < cy);
            Console.WriteLine("x>y = {0}", cx > cy);
            Console.WriteLine("x==y = {0}", cx == cy);
            Console.WriteLine("x!=y = {0}", cx != cy);

            Value name = ValueFactory.Create("Jeffrey Schultz", ValueType.String);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} == You = {1}", name, name == "You");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IValueComparer
{
    bool GreaterThan(string source, string destination);
    bool LessThan(string source, string destination);
}

public class IntToIntComparer : IValueComparer
{
    public bool GreaterThan(string source, string detination)
    {
        // better use TryParse and handle exception
        return Int32.Parse(source) > Int32.Parse(detination);
    }

    public bool LessThan(string source, string detination)
    {
        // better use TryParse and handle exception
        return Int32.Parse(source) < Int32.Parse(detination);
    }
}

public class DateToDateComparer : IValueComparer
{
    public bool GreaterThan(string source, string detination)
    {
        // better use TryParse and handle exception
        return DateTime.Parse(source) > DateTime.Parse(detination);
    }

    public bool LessThan(string source, string detination)
    {
        // better use TryParse and handle exception
        return DateTime.Parse(source) < DateTime.Parse(detination);
    }
}

public class StringToStringComparer : IValueComparer
{
    public bool GreaterThan(string source, string detination)
    {
        return source.Length > detination.Length;
    }

    public bool LessThan(string source, string detination)
    {
        return source.Length < detination.Length;
    }
}


public class Condition
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public IValueComparer Comparer{get; set;}

    public static string Integer { get { return "Integer"; } }
    public static string String { get { return "String"; } }
    public static string DateTime { get { return "DateTime"; } }

    public static Condition CreateForType(string type)
    {
        if (type == Integer)
            return new Condition { Type = type, Comparer = new IntToIntComparer() };
        if (type == String)
            return new Condition { Type = type, Comparer = new StringToStringComparer() };
        if (type == DateTime)
            return new Condition { Type = type, Comparer = new DateToDateComparer() };
        return null;
    }

    public bool GreaterThan(Condition destination)
    {
        return Comparer.GreaterThan(Value, destination.Value);
    }

    public static bool operator >(Condition source, Condition destination)
    {
        return source.GreaterThan(destination);
    }

    public static bool operator <(Condition source, Condition destination)
    {
        return source.LessThan(destination);
    }

    public bool LessThan(Condition destination)
    {
        return Comparer.LessThan(Value, destination.Value);
    }
}
```

---

```
        var condition1 = Condition.CreateForType("Integer");
        condition1.ID = 1;
        condition1.Value = "5";

        var condition2 = Condition.CreateForType("Integer");
        condition2.ID = 2;
        condition2.Value = "10";

        bool result1 = condition1 > condition2;
        bool result2 = condition1.LessThan(condition2);
```

Comment: But I'm getting the data from the database at runtime, not sure how this will work?

Comment: how do you get the data from database, give an example

Comment: You need to create a class that represents the data type defined by the conditionType, such as IntegerType. IntegerType knows how to compare integer values. Also, you would need a Condition that accepts a value and a data type handler.

Comment: @MohamedAbed I gave an example of my database columns in the question, so I will return rows with values for those columns.

Comment: How will this allow you to compare numerics? How would you write "your code here"? I am pretty sure if you write "if (source > destination)", it won't compile.

Comment: Updated answer with a sample solution