# How to create a class or set of classes that represent a Value, be it an integer or string or list of strings

Tags: c#, design-patterns

How can I represent, in a class, something that represents a Value.

This value will be used to write comparison operations on, like EqualTo, GreaterThan etc.

Now the catch is, *the value could sometimes be an integer, string, or even a list of integers or strings.*

How could I represent this in a class or groups of classes (maybe inheriting from a base class)

Could I then write a single method like:

```
EqualTo(IValue value, IValue otherValue)
```

**How could this EqualTo method handle now if I passed in a string, or a list of strings, datetime or a list of datetimes and return true/false accordingly?**

Note:

The catch is I will be building up these objects from data that comes from the database, so the actual dataType, value or values etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write:

```
EqualTo<T>(T value1, T value2) where T : IEquatable<T>
```

or for greater than and less than:

```
Compare<T>(T value1, T value2) where T : IComparable<T>
```

Both of those would be pretty simple, given `IComparable<T>` and `IEquatable<T>` :)

You'd need separate overloads (or different methods) to handle a *sequence* of such values though:

```
SequenceEqualTo<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence1, IEnumerable<T> sequence2)
    where T : IEquatable<T>


SequenceCompare<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence1, IEnumerable<T> sequence2)
    where T : IComparable<T>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the generic constraint, you could use `Comparer<T>.Default` and `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

If you wanted to handle sequences in the same methods as non-sequences, you could always check whether `T` implemented `IEquatable<T>` and if not, whether it implemented `IEnumerable<TElement>` for some `TElement` which implemented `IEquatable<TElement>`. It would get pretty confusing, mind you...

EDIT: Okay, if you're going to be given these things dynamically...

- First work out whether they're lists or not. You'll want to handle that separately. Assuming it really is `List<T>`, you could do:

  ```
  if (value1.GetType().IsGenericType &&
      value1.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
  {
      // Handle this case separately, definitely in another method.
      // It'll be a pain.
  }
  ```
- Otherwise, use just the normal `Equals()` call to check for equality, and cast a value to the non-generic `IComparable` type for greater-than/less-than. It's not ideal, but it should work...

Comment: I updated my question as the data will be built via the db, so this will be dynamic in nature.

Comment: @codecompleting: Okay, that changes things completely. Do you even know whether the types will be the same? You don't want to start comparing an `int` with a list of strings...

Comment: sorry about that, my mistake.  Yes you can assume the types will be the same (assuming you mean when in a list/collection).

Comment: @codecompleting: Okay, I've edited my answer. Basically it's going to be a pain :(

Comment: so to make it more concrete, say I am getting a row back from the db table that has the Condition data type, value, how would I map it to an object?   a little confused.

Comment: @codecompleting: I don't know what you mean - how are you getting it back to start with? If you've already got the type of value as a separate field, you could surely call a generic method with that and avoid all the nastiness.

Comment: I'm getting the value from a record in the database, i.e. the column will have 1 for integer, 2 for string, etc., which I am currently just setting a dataType enumeration on my object.

Comment: @codecompleting: So why not just switch on that value, and call a generic method as per my first version?

Comment: oh so you mean repeat the generic method in the switch, passing in the type <int>, <string> ?

Comment: (uddated link) I was also thinking of creating a smarter Value class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918686/how-to-map-values-in-the-db-to-my-objects-when-the-type-is-known-at-runtime

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4554/discussion-between-codecompleting-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @codecompleting: You could always do that *in* the relevant class. It doesn't really matter much.

Comment: (Sorry, I don't tend to do chat - I have too many other things going on at once.)

Comment: (I actually was just testing that out, didn't expect you to be there)

Comment: how can EqualTo<T> and SequenceEqualTo<T> are seperate classes right?  you said overloads but since the generic constraint is different they obv. are in different classes right?

Comment: So constraints can go on methods?

Comment: @codecompleting: For generic methods, yes. Now might be a good time to take a break from your ultimate aim, and learn a bit more about generics :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to make sure your types implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) and use its [CompareTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx) method.